# Need to copy several sheets from one workbook onto another

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with several sheets, I need my code to loop through all sheets and just copy onto another workbook those sheets which meet the following criteria: 1) are visible,  2) its name is not 'Menu'.

My current code starts looping but once it copies the first sheet that meets the criteria, it stops and I don't know why.

```
With wbFrom
    For Each ws In .Sheets
        If (ws.Visible = True And ws.Name <> "Menu") Then
            ws.Copy After:=wbTo.Sheets(wbTo.Sheets.Count)
            .Activate
        End If
    Next ws
End With
```

End Function

Comment: What happens if you leave out the `.Activate`? Where does your cursor go if you add a breakpoint on the `ws.`Copy` line and step through?

Comment: @Piemol the destination workbook is activated and the active sheet is the recently copied sheet from wbFrom. however, only that sheet was copied and the code stops there

Comment: Add `Else: Debug.Print ws.Name` before `End If` and see what is written in the Immediate window.

Comment: Yes I understand, but what if you remove the line `.Activate`  ? And what is the next step if you step though the code with a breakbpoint on the line `ws.Copy` ?

Comment: Your code seems a bit inaccurate: if `ws` is declared `As Worksheet`, you should loop through the worksheets collection i.e. use `... In .Worksheets`. You probably don't need the line `.Activate`. If you think you do, please share the reason why. Depending on what you did before these lines, the code might work or not. Please share the preceding code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work unless you have not defined both your workbooks properly. Also, good idea to keep `Option Explicit` at the top of your module to require variable declaration.

```
Dim wbFrom As Workbook
Dim wbTo As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wbFrom = Workbooks("SourceFileName.xlsx")
Set wbTo = Workbooks("TargetFileName.xlsx")
```